# Arduino PID temperature controller

Tags: arduino, temperature, pid-controller

I am running the below code on an Arduino Uno and it is partially working. 
I will try to explain the problem step by step:

1. I start the soldering station from AC 230V
2. The soldering station heats up to maximum (I measure 18mV on the TC at maximum)
3. I reduce voluntary the temperature by rotating the pot to the minimum
4. The temperature (and the voltage on the TC) starts to decrease
5. When the voltage on the TC is about 16-17mV then the power to the soldering iron starts to increase suddenly. And I cannot do anything to make it stable or to decrease it.
6. The voltage on the TC continues to rise, and when it reaches 22-23mV, I unplug the soldering station from the wall socket, to protect the heater of the soldering iron.

I tried the following solutions for my problem: I checked individually each part of the schematic and all of them were good.
I found that this event happens, when in the code the PID error is equal (=) to set point. This makes the PID value to be 7400 and in the `delayMicroseconds(maximum_firing_delay - PID_value);` line of code the result is zero (0), making the entire sine wave to be present on the soldering iron heater. I measured those things in serial monitor.I have also monitored the voltage on the TC and on the output of the OpAmp and it seems to be ok, with no spikes or suddenly increases or decreases.

Schematic: https://ibb.co/hKn5kjL

```
//Inputs and outputs
int firing_pin = 5;
int zero_cross = 2;

//Variables
int last_CH1_state = 0;
bool zero_cross_detected = false;
int firing_delay = 7400;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int maximum_firing_delay = 7400;
/*Later in the code you will se that the maximum delay after the zero detection
 * is 7400. Why? Well, we know that the 220V AC voltage has a frequency of around 50-60HZ so
 * the period is between 20ms and 16ms, depending on the country. We control the firing
 * delay each half period so each 10ms or 8 ms. To amke sure we wont pass thsoe 10ms, I've made tests
 * and the 7400us or 7.4ms was a good value. Measure your frequency and chande that value later */
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

unsigned long previousMillis = 0; 
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
int temp_read_Delay = 500;
int real_temperature = 0;
int setpoint = 100;

//PID variables
float PID_error = 0;
float previous_error = 0;
float elapsedTime, Time, timePrev;
int PID_value = 0;
//PID constants
int kp = 30;   int ki= 10;   int kd = 15;
int PID_p = 0;    int PID_i = 0;    int PID_d = 0;


void setup() {
  //Define the pins
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode (firing_pin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (zero_cross,INPUT);   
  PCICR |= (1 << PCIE2);    //enable scan                                                 
  PCMSK2 |= (1 << PCINT18);  //Set pin D2 (zero cross input) trigger an interrupt on state change.
}


void loop() {    
  currentMillis = millis();           //Save the value of time before the loop
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= temp_read_Delay){
    previousMillis += temp_read_Delay;              //Increase the previous time for next loop
    //get the real temperature in Celsius degrees
    // added by Mike
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    real_temperature += analogRead(A0);  
    real_temperature /= 50;
    real_temperature = map(real_temperature, 0, 550, 25, 400);
    // end added by Mike
    setpoint = analogRead(A1);
    setpoint = map(setpoint, 0, 1023, 150, 400);
    PID_error = setpoint - real_temperature;        //Calculate the pid ERROR

    if(PID_error > 30)                              //integral constant will only affect errors below 30ºC             
    {PID_i = 0;}

    PID_p = kp * PID_error;                         //Calculate the P value
    PID_i = PID_i + (ki * PID_error);               //Calculate the I value
    timePrev = Time;                    // the previous time is stored before the actual time read
    Time = millis();                    // actual time read
    elapsedTime = (Time - timePrev) / 1000;   
    PID_d = kd*((PID_error - previous_error)/elapsedTime);  //Calculate the D value
    PID_value = PID_p + PID_i + PID_d;                      //Calculate total PID value

    //We define firing delay range between 0 and 7400. Read above why 7400!!!!!!!
    if(PID_value < 0) // initial it was <
    {      PID_value = 0;       }
    if(PID_value > 7400) // initial it was >
    {      PID_value = 7400;    }
    previous_error = PID_error; //Remember to store the previous error.
//    Serial.println("PID_error=");
//    Serial.println(PID_error);
//    Serial.println("real_temperature=");
//    Serial.println(real_temperature);
//    Serial.println("setpoint=");
//    Serial.println(setpoint);
//    Serial.println("PID_value=");
//    Serial.println(PID_value);
  }

  //If the zero cross interruption was detected we create the 100us firing pulse  
  if (zero_cross_detected)     
    {
      delayMicroseconds(maximum_firing_delay - PID_value); //This delay controls the power
      digitalWrite(firing_pin,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(100);
      digitalWrite(firing_pin,LOW);
      zero_cross_detected = false;
    } 
}

//This is the interruption routine (pind D8(zero cross), D11(increase) and D12(decrease))
//----------------------------------------------

ISR(PCINT2_vect){
  ///////////////////////////////////////Input from optocoupler
  if(PIND & B00000100){            //We make an AND with the state register, We verify if pin D2 is HIGH???
    if(last_CH1_state == 0){       //If the last state was 0, then we have a state change...
      zero_cross_detected = true;  //We have detected a state change! We need both falling and rising edges
    }
  }
  else if(last_CH1_state == 1){    //If pin 2 is LOW and the last state was HIGH then we have a state change      
    zero_cross_detected = true;    //We haev detected a state change!  We need both falling and rising edges.
    last_CH1_state = 0;            //Store the current state into the last state for the next loop
    }
}
```

Comment: You should map the output of the PID to your hardware, which is reversed: when you want high drive, you use low values. Something like "triac = 220-pid_output", given that pid_output goes from 0 to 218.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I got a wave form that sometimes has a higher RMS voltage and sometimes a lower RMS voltage just like it is moving on the screen from right to left.

Comment: Try to debug your application, use the console to print out the input and output from the pid, and the drive you send to the triac. In the code you posted I don't see this "reversing".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I have updated the code. It does not work. I got a wave form that sometimes has a higher RMS voltage and sometimes a lower RMS voltage and it is moving on the screen from right to left.

Comment: It sounds like you need first need to spend some time gaining an understanding of triac AC "dimming" and the way that chops cycles.  It also sounds like you may need to learn to use the trigger of your scope (?)  - try setting it to line.  Hopefully this circuit is running from an *isolated* drop down transformer, otherwise it is potentially deadly.

Comment: Additionally the structure of your program is very unwise: you shouldn't do delays of up to an A/C cycle period in an ISR.  And you shouldn't repeatedly disable interrupts to change the value and a main loop that is probably running many, many, many times faster than the ISR.  And then you have both the main loop and the ISR trying to use the same A/D converter without any coordination... Is this original core, or are you perhaps following a tutorial written by someone who didn't have a very sound idea of what they were doing?

Comment: Ok, the "reversing" seems correct; in "46*triac" that 46 seems a little high, 46*220 yields 10120 (>10000) which could keep the triac always on, but the numbers should work, at least in the middle of the range. Try to serial.print the pid_output in the zero_cross() (only numbers, no lengthy strings like "pid output..."). Doing so, you can see the set_point and the input from hardware, and the pid_output from serial, and the triac driving is easy to calculate by hand. This debugging should show you everything you need to see the problem.

Comment: Another thing: @ChrisStratton is correct about the structure of the program, and I must add that probably the PID runs too much frequently (this should be checked). If the PID sees that the process variable "input" changes very slowly (normally temperature is slow), it can result in being too much aggressive and jump quickly to fully ON or fully OFF. You can call the PID  only 1 time every 100 in the interrupt (quick and dirty solution). But debugging as suggested above should clear the situation.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I updated the code and I checked the output of the PID. The output of the PID is always 128 (please have a look at the code).

Comment: Trying to debug this is pointless given ADC conflicts, etc.  You need to tear up the code and re-write something sane.  Do all the measurements in the main loop.  Get the delays out of the ISR by using a hardware timer for the phase chopping.  No point in even thinking about PID until you have a sane program structure for the inputs and outputs.  In fact, start by just making a "dimmer" where one of your potentiometers adjusts the A/C duty cycle and make sure that you have a nice range of adjustment with no "wrapping" at the end where minimum duty cycle suddenly becomes maximum or the reverse.

Comment: You took out the "reversing", and this is wrong: high output -> low heating. Anyway, if output is always 128 then the PID is trying to heat. This information is useless if you don't know *why*: hopefully, this is because the setpoint is higher that the input. But if you put setpoint to minimum PID output should lower (did you try that?). You must observe and observe and observe. You can NOT post here the code, which is only half of the information, and expect somebody tells you what is happening. When PID is 128, what are input and setpoint?

Comment: I have updated the code. With this new code, the soldering station is almost working, but if I set the max temperature, which corresponds to 18mV on TC, then, when I reduce the temp from the potentiometer, the voltage on the TC starts to decrease, but when it reach 17mV, the voltage on the TC starts to rise again up to 22mV, when I unplug from the wall the entire circuit with the 24V/100VA transformer. I tried to identify the problem, but I did not find it yet. Any help would be very important... @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica

Comment: It seems an hardware problem. Observe the signal from the TC (thermocouple?) when it enters the CPU after the amplifier: is it stable? Maybe you need more HW filtering. When you detach the 24Vac, the zero cross ceases and perhaps the power supply gets cleaner and stops polluting the amplifier. You can also implement a software filter.

Comment: Anyway, my compliments for having implemented the PID instead of using a black box PID. You have more control.

Comment: You need to observe the TC output (after the amplifier) under various temperatures and situations (24Vac on and off), write down the data, and analyze them. You can find anomalies (power supply polluting the reading), inertia, imprecisions which you can correct in software. I would do software filtering anyway, and print temperature every second or so. Maybe that when triac does not fire (no 24Vac or PID output off) the reading is higher by a percent or an offset. If so, you can introduce software correction. "No 24ac" and "PID off" are different, they can sum up or not.

Comment: I have checked again, I didn't saw any problem with the voltage from the output of the amplifier, I have also eliminated IC1B, and used directly the output of the IC1A. https://ibb.co/0X4gvgS
https://ibb.co/gSrMq0G The first image is when the temp reach the maximum value, and the second image is when I reduce the temp from the pot and when it reach about 1.8V at the output of the opamp. I used the multimeter to measure the output.

Comment: I have also checked the output of the potentiometer and it looks good. When the temperature decrease and there appears on the screen the full sinewave, then even if I would rotate the pot anyway, the sine wave does not modifies.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica he didn't implement this one either, he copied it from http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut39_code1.php

Comment: Yes, the code I copied from that site, but I modified it for my application

Comment: Mike, I don't understand. At first you talk about mV signal from TC, then you use a multimeter to check the op-amp, and the scope to look at the 24Vac? Use always the scope, and you will find something wrong somewhere!

Comment: @ChrisStratton well, one important thing is he now can see what the PID is doing, and another thing he restructured the program a little.

Comment: SImulate the whole process in your mind, and check instant by instant the various voltage levels or software variables. If something happens that you don't expect, you can see which input is unexpected, or which formula does bad calculations.

Comment: I have found that the event occurs when the pid_error is = to set_point, and then the output of the PID is 7400.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica The event occurs when the output of the pid is equal to 7400. After this event, even if I rotate the pot, the iron continues to heat up.

Comment: debug debug debug. You talked about voltage on TC rising even without power supply, now you are talking about something else. We discussed too much.

Comment: The temperature on the TC increases only when the output of the pid is equal to 7400. And then it continues to increase. There is always power supply voltage in this situation.

Comment: Run the circuit with battery, you will see it works better. Advice from an old industrial automation expert: Never use the analog inputs and outputs on an micro processor!

Comment: Can you provide a plot of the input and outputs over time? This would help verify if the problem lies with the PID itself, or something else. Even simulating a faux input signal might provide insight into its behavior.

Comment: @mike_mike What is the part # for TC_1 and TC_2 have you verified that the thermocouple is monitoring the right temperatures? (usually I do two temps, like 25C and 100C minimum, or graph a know tempterature side by side with the new sensor\hardware)

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63631/fan-regulator-control-from-arduino/63674?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C26.8685#63674) Arduino SE answer I offer two sketches which demonstrate Triac control. This is one of them:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

const byte INTERRUPT_PIN = 2;
const byte TRIAC_PIN = 4;
const byte TRIAC_PULSE_MICROS = 30;

const int FADE_MAX = 9800;
const int FADE_MIN = 2000;

volatile bool triacOn;
volatile int period = FADE_MIN; // microseconds cut out from AC pulse

int fadeAmount = 10;

void zeroCrossing() {
  triacOn = false; // triac tuns off self at zero crossing
  Timer1.setPeriod(period); // to call triacPulse() after off period
}

void triacPulse() {
  if (triacOn) { // stop pulse
    digitalWrite(TRIAC_PIN, LOW);
    Timer1.stop();
  } else { // start pulse
    digitalWrite(TRIAC_PIN, HIGH);
    triacOn = true;
    Timer1.setPeriod(TRIAC_PULSE_MICROS);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(TRIAC_PIN, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), zeroCrossing, RISING);
  Timer1.initialize();
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(triacPulse);
}

void loop() {
  period = period + fadeAmount;
  if (period <= FADE_MIN || period >= FADE_MAX) {
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
  }
  delay(25);
}
```

the other uses direct registers access of AVR.

EDIT:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75194/arduino-pid-controller-for-triac

mike's oscilloscope output of the sketch above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnfy_EsPlVI

here are the input and output values of mike's code based on this answer (blue is temperature, red is output for the Triac period):

[image]